# findHomography producing inaccurate transformation matrix

Tags: python, opencv, matrix, homography

I have the coordinates of the four corners of a table in my image frame as well as the actual dimensions of that table. What I want to do is find the transformation matrix from the table in the frame (first image) to the actual table (second image). The goal is to be able to map points in the raw frame (location of a ball when it bounces) to where it bounced in the second image rectangle.

I have tried using openCV's `findHomography` however I am getting inaccurate results. I am trying to find the matrix `T = A -> B` where:

**A**: the coordinates of table corners in the raw image (see first image):

```
[[512.10633894 269.22351997]  # Bottom corner
 [325.78198672 236.36953072]  # Left Corner
 [536.67952727 199.18259532]  # Top Corner
 [715.21023044 214.80199122]] # Right Corner
```

**B**: Actual coordinates to map to (see second image):

```
[[152.5   0. ]
 [  0.    0. ]
 [  0.  274. ]
 [152.5 274. ]]
```

**T**: Transformation matrix

```
[[-5.96154850e-01 -3.38096031e+00  9.92931129e+02]
 [-5.59829402e-01  3.17495425e+00 -5.68494643e+02]
 [-2.76038296e-04 -8.61104226e-03  1.00000000e+00]]
```

Using `findHomography` gives me the transformation matrix **T**, but when I input the original coordinates **A** I expect to get **B** but I end up with **B'**:

```
[[[-221    0   -1]]
 [[   0    0   -1]]
 [[   0 -235    0]]
 [[-159 -285   -1]]]
```

This is of the correct magnitude so it seems like it's doing something right but is nowhere near the accuracy I want, and for some reason all the values are negative which I don't understand why. Why is **B'** not equal to **B**?

Here is the relevant code:

```
T, status = cv.findHomography(img_corners, TABLE_COORDS, cv.RANSAC, 5.)
T_img = cv.transform(img_corners.reshape((-1, 1, 2)), T)
```

I have also tried changing the 5.0 parameter to something lower but without any luck...

[image: Table In frame]

[image: Actual dimensions of table]

Comment: can you try `cv2.getPerspectiveTransformation`?  When you only ave 4 points there is no need to use findHomography at all. However I think it should not make a difference in the result.

Comment: what's `T_img = cv.transform(pts.reshape((-1, 1, 2)), T)` supposed to do? What is `pts`? Can you try `T_img = cv.perspectiveTransform(pts.reshape((-1, 1, 2)), T)` instead?

Comment: `cv.transform` is not the application of a  perspective homography: https://docs.opencv.org/5.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga393164aa54bb9169ce0a8cc44e08ff22

Comment: @Micka Sorry, `pts` should be `img_corners`, Will change that now. What I am trying to do with `T_img` is test the transformation matrix to see if it makes sense, ideally `T_img` should be equal to `TABLE_COORDS`

Comment: I mean what you expect `cv.transform` to do. Imho you will need cv.perspectiveTransform instead. Interesting that cv.transform did not throw an error, since it should only accept 2x2 and 2x3 transformations as input, according to the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: Turns out you rounded your output matrix too soon and forgot to "normalize" it with the last coordinate.

```
T_img /= T_img[:, 0, 2].reshape([4, 1, 1])
print(T_img)
```

Result seems fine if you ignore SC notation:

```
[[[ 1.5249998e+02 -1.8539389e-05  1.0000000e+00]]

 [[-3.9001084e-06 -3.6695651e-06  1.0000000e+00]]

 [[-1.1705048e-05  2.7400000e+02  1.0000000e+00]]

 [[ 1.5249997e+02  2.7399997e+02  1.0000000e+00]]]
```

**Alternative way**: I use getPerspectiveTransform instead, which should be doing same thing essentially.

```
input_pts = np.float32([    [512.10633894, 269.22351997],  # Bottom corner
                            [325.78198672, 236.36953072],  # Left Corner
                            [536.67952727, 199.18259532],  # Top Corner
                            [715.21023044, 214.80199122]])
output_pts = np.float32([   [152.5, 0.0],
                            [  0.0, 0.0],
                            [  0.0, 274.0],
                            [152.5, 274.0]])
matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(input_pts, output_pts)
print(matrix)
```

Result:

```
[[-5.95356887e-01 -3.37643559e+00  9.92043065e+02]
 [-5.58341286e-01  3.16651417e+00 -5.66569957e+02]
 [-2.74644869e-04 -8.59569964e-03  1.00000000e+00]]
```

Let's check now:

```
x = np.float32([512.10633894, 269.22351997, 1.0])
res = np.dot(matrix, x)
print(res)
print(res / res[2])
```

Result (remember it should be normalized with last coordinate):

```
[-221.85880447    0.           -1.45481181]
[152.50000261  -0.           1.        ]
```

Seems to be working.

I suspect your output vector somehow got rounded to `int` and lost all precision. The way you are asking about negatives also implies you forgot to "unscale" them.

Comment: Thanks this works great, I didn't fully understand what that third column of the transformation matrix represented, should have been more thorough reading through the docs...

Comment: Your code actually works as well. You just rounded your vector prematurely. I'll add an edit at the front now.